# How to extract a zip file to a SFTP Laravel Storage driver?

Tags: laravel, filesystems, sftp

I want to extract a file to a remote location using the Laravel File Storage system.

This is my code:

```
$zipPath = $request->zip_file_label;

            // get the absolute path to $zipPath
            $path = pathinfo(realpath($zipPath), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            $res = $zip->open($zipPath);
            if ($res === TRUE) {

                $zip->extractTo(Storage::disk('remote')->path('test_path'));
                $zip->close();
                echo "WOOT! $zipPath extracted!";
            } else {
                echo "Doh! I couldn't open $zipPath";
            }
```

This is my `filesystems.php`:

```
'remote' => [
            'driver' => 'sftp',
            'host' => '11.111.111.1',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'root' => '/var/www'
        ]
```

At the moment this is not working it extracts the zip file to my local server in the location `public/test_path`

The overall goal is to extract the file that is located on the main server (where the laravel application is) and to send the contents of the zip to the SFTP server.

Comment: No, I want to extract the file that is located on the main server (where the laravel application is) and to send the contents of the zip to the SFTP server. Or ideally to the the transfer and the extraction with one operation. But overall the goal is to send the contents of the zip file to the SFTP server.

Comment: If you can do SFTP you can generally also SSH to the server so upload and then SSH and run an unzip command there. `extractTo` only works with local paths

Comment: @apokryfos yeah but the goal is to achieve this task automatically from an admin area. So manual ssh access is not an option.

Comment: I never said anything about *manual* SSH access. You can use [SSH2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) or an `exec`-like option. Laravel ships with the [Symfony Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) component that makes it easier.